# Way to initialize payment using ussd in rails application and make a payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, payment-gateway, ussd

I have a requirement to integrate a ussd payment to one of my web application built in rails.

I have gone through many of the links suggested by googling, but I couldn't get the exact place to start with.

I want to use the africastalking apis or the services to make it possiable .

Can any one please suggest me the place to start about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hello Depending on your location, you may have to visit your Gsm Network operator to avail you direct APIs to connect and accept payments via ussd payment. or you could look at this http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=133391.0  if you would like to try that